# Starting NodeJS - what code to look for?

Tags: node.js

We have a whiteboard application powered by NodeJS sitting on a 'cloud' server (rackspace cloud). I recently scaled our server up to accommodate for the anticipated traffic with our launch, and in the process it shut down NodeJS. We are launching our product in a few hours, and our NodeJS developer has gone for the day.

The whiteboard application is supposed to run at http://rayku.com:8001 (the port is opened). However, it's not working because the port isn't listening to anything with NodeJS shut down.

I honestly have no idea which js file to run in order to start NodeJS for the whiteboard. There are many js files in a 'whiteboard' folder. Do you know what type of code I should look for that might suggest it is the right one? Or, do you know what types of logs I can dig up that might point me in the right direction?

Much appreciated

Comment: If you've got time still, we have an [awesome chat facility](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/642/node-js) where people could be gathered to help you PDQ. Alternately, call the dev and ask him what to do. If you go in there, use `@jcolebrand` to get ahold of me more quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Look for app.js, server.js or something similar.  It isn't required but a lot of people use app.js from what I have seen.
- node or nodejs is typically the command to start.  You may need to set environmental variables or arguments depending on how the developer set things up.
- Also make sure to run it with screen or forever so it doesn't quit when you log out.

For common code. `createServer` is probably what is used to open the server itself.  That is consistent between the core libraries and a lot of the frameworks.  There might be another file that loads the module prior to executing so running might not work.

Comment: Yes, I see an app.js! Do you know if this is the correct code to run in SSH? nohup node app.js > logs.txt &

Comment: That should work I think.  It is possible the app needs arguments though so it may fail.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind elaborating? I ran it and unfortunately you're right - it still did not work. http://rayku.com:8001

Comment: The app may depend on environmental variables or command line arguments.  Try searching for `process.argv` and `process.env`

Comment: Also it might be late, but you might want to check the init scripts to verify the developer didn't write one and forgot to add it to the defaults.

Comment: He doesn't know **how** to do that.

Comment: I'm making the most out of google right now, but it's a little bit confusing. I did find an environment.js with this code, though I'm not sure if it's relevant: `exports.memoryUsage = process.memoryUsage();
setInterval(function () {
    exports.memoryUsage = process.memoryUsage();
}, 10000);`

Comment: Fixed! Was able to restart it by going into whiteboard.git/hooks where all the git hooks live, and just ran sh post-receive to restart the whiteboard server :)